# Headers in Rails, Cache, Firefox impropriety

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, caching

Folks!
I have a problem, for example, user join on my page and do some actions, write comments, and push "Back" in Firefox, he looks old content (cache). I'm using Rails 2.3, but don't know, ho to fix it. I need that user push "back" in FF, he will see updated content, not from FF cache. Apologize for my english. :) Thank for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent the browser cache by calling (before_filter :prevent_browser_cache ) the following code:

```
def prevent_browser_cache
  headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
  headers["Cache-Control"] = "must-revalidate"   
  headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache"   
  headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-store"       
end
```

Answer (score 0):

for Rails 3 and 4 you can try this gem https://github.com/equivalent/no_cache_control